# SQL Server Query invalid column in select list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a function that will return a table of all cows that produced on average more than 20 liters of milk per day.
This is the code I came up with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SuperCows (@year int)
RETURNS @supercows TABLE (
    Name nvarchar(50),
    AvgMilk decimal(4,2)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT @supercows
        SELECT c.Name, AVG(CAST(p.MilkQuantity AS decimal(4,2))) FROM MilkProduction AS p
        INNER JOIN Cows AS c ON c.IDCow = p.CowID
        WHERE YEAR(p.Date) = @year
        GROUP BY p.CowID
        HAVING AVG(CAST(p.MilkQuantity AS decimal(4,2))) > 20
    RETURN
END
GO
```

The error that I get when trying to create the function is this:

```
Column 'Cows.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

My knowledge of SQL is fairly limited and I was hoping someone cold help me with solving this.

Comment: just add c.Name to the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Cows.name to the group by list:

```
SELECT c.Name, AVG(CAST(p.MilkQuantity AS decimal(4,2))) FROM MilkProduction AS p
    INNER JOIN Cows AS c ON c.IDCow = p.CowID
    WHERE YEAR(p.Date) = @year
    GROUP BY p.CowID, c.Name
    HAVING AVG(CAST(p.MilkQuantity AS decimal(4,2))) > 20
```

If you are using `group by` every field you select needs to either be in the list being grouped by or have an aggregate function applied to the column (`AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, etc) as there can be multiple values returned for each of the non-grouped-by columns.

Comment: Indeed I do. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
GROUP BY p.CowID
```

to

```
GROUP BY c.Name
```

This won't work if you have multiple cows with the same name - in that case their total MilkQuantity will be combined into a single record.

Comment: What if two different cows have the same name?

Comment: OP doesn't return ID in the query, so I guess he doesn't care about this scenario. If we do group by both ID and Name and return just name - you would just see duplicate names - which is not much information

Comment: In your scenario two separate Bessie's could combine and be a `supercow` even if they weren't. Relevant even if he is not selecting the id.

Comment: I liked typing `supercow`

Comment: @Matthew I have even seen her: http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/cow_flying.gif